# Detect login timeout with AJAX and log back in with .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am getting an unknown error when Ajax update panels submit a request after 1 hour. The request is not going to the server.

If the request goes to the server, the server will automatically redirect to the login page. I am trying to force the page to send the request to the server, so the server will take care of the login page.

Finally, I was able to handle the error when the error occurred, **but how can I force it to submit the request to the server using JavaScript or jQuery?.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
  function EndRequestHandler(sender, args){
     if (args.get_error() != undefined){
          args.set_errorHandled(true);
     }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you've been logged out of the application. Take the URL you's using in AJAX and paste it into the browser's URL. See what you get back.

Comment: I am getting login apge. Somehow this error is blocking me to submit  to server or redirecting to login page.

Comment: No, your session is timing out. This has nothing to do with your ajax, but you should detect it and automatically log back in and re-send the request.

Comment: How can detect and resend the request?

Comment: Dunno. I'll rename your question and see what we get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function call: `__doPostBack('', '');`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jQuery to submit the form like this:

```
$("#myForm").submit();
```